# Rethinkdb Select multiple rows from selection/sequence by array of row number

Tags: rethinkdb, rethinkdb-javascript

For a given sequence, how can I fetch rows of certain row numbers(indices).
I know that `nth()` can select the nth index. But what if I want to select multiple rows by index ?

```
r.expr([0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50]).nth(3)    // gives 30
```

The above works. But, how do I get the following ?

```
r.expr([0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50]).nth([3, 5, 2])    // gives [30, 50, 20]
```

Answer (score 0):

You may be better using slice:

> selection.slice(startOffset[, endOffset, {leftBound:'closed', rightBound:'open'}]) → selection

The docs are [here.](https://www.rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/slice/)